# Dealing with OAuth in Aurelia framework

Tags: aurelia

I have created an AuthService in aurelia, with a function `getToken()`. That function gets the current `access_token` in localStorage. If the token is expired, the function use the `refresh_token` to ask for a new one to the server.

The other services which require authorization, use the AutheService injected to use the `getToken()` and pass the Bearer TOKEN in the Authorization header.

The problem is that a page can use 10 services which require authorization. Then the `getToken()` is being called 10 times and a new token is asked for the server 10 times if the current is expired.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: If you use the Aurelia container for DI, your AuthService is a Singleton by default (if you did not change it). As Javascript is single threaded (if you don't use web workers), you simply need to add a flag which changes for the first request of a new token. All subsequent calls will get the refreshed token of the first call.